# magento2 in production mode Nwdthemes Revslider not working

Tags: magento2, slider

On local server in developer mode revslider works fine. When change mode to production, enable all caches slider not working.
My steps on production server:
 1. eneble all cashes
 2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
 3. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
In console no errors, and slider not shoving